# Javascript redefine Infinity, NaN, or "" as 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript calculator which accepts user input, does some math and writes the result to the input field "#theResult"

Since "#theResult" updates on keyup, there are times when "#theResult" will return Infinity, NaN, or "" until all of the fields are filled out. Until all of the fields are filled out, I want "#theResult" to return 0 instead. Here is the code:

```
if (theResult === Infinity || theResult === "" || theResult === NaN) {
    theResult === 0;
}
$("#theResult").val(theResult);
```

The full code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/33/)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You use toFixed(...) in your code, so "theResult" variable will always be a String.

Comment: You're probably better off just using `theResult = theResult || 0;`

Comment: That said, `NaN` has a particular meaning when used within an equation, and replacing it with `0` is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Ivan Kuckler since toFixed returns a string, how do you append a zero to a single digit decimal. Say to represnt $10.50 ?

Comment: @zzzBov I tried using theResult = theResult || 0 after removing toFixed. Still get Infinity if I enter into "price" field first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've used `theResult === 0` where you should have used `theResult = 0`.

The `===` is for comparisons. When you want to **change** the value of a variable, you use the assignment operator `=`.

Like @zzzzBov said, the simplest thing to do is replace the whole thing with

```
 theResult = isFinite(theResult) && theResult || 0; // updated
```

That glosses over the subtleties of `NaN` however; if the user is finished and the result really is `NaN`, showing that as `0` is not really correct.

Comment: In addition to what @Pointy said, `theResult === NaN` will always return false. What you want instead is `if (theResult === Infinity || theResult === "" || isNaN(theResult)) {`

Comment: @CaseyFoster oh yes, that's a really important point. Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: Yeah but still: `NaN !== NaN` Use `isNaN(NaN) // true`

Comment: Thanks for explaining "=" vs "===" syntax as I am a bit new to javascript. However theResult = theResult || 0 does not seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/RqzPk/37/ as it still returns Infinity or NaN

Comment: @HelloWorld your jsfiddle seems to work fine when I try it.

Comment: @Pointy Try entering something into "price" field first. Returns infinity. Your first suggestion did work however.

Comment: @HelloWorld ah OK, sorry; `Infinity` isn't falsy in JavaScript. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Pointy The code you updated worked perfectly as well! I get what is going on now. We are telling theResult that it equals a finite version of it'self or 0. In my particular case, if the user finishes with NaN it's because they left a field blank. I will create a alert to tell them to fill out all of the fields, until then 0 rather than NaN is cosmetic.